# Setting an image to link to itself and open in colorbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I have an image that has been resized via CSS to show as 100x100px on an HTML page. When clicked, I want to open the image in a colorbox - so the user can see the non resized/squashed version as it will normally appear.

I've worked out how to set the path of the href to itself (so this doesn't have to be changed every time) (see below), although not sure how to get the colorbox part working - i tried changing 'each' to 'colorbox' - as per how you would normally assign the colorbox, and it opens, it just doesn't load the image in it :S

Any pointers would be great -

```
<div class="logoImage"><img src="../tym_img_shared/background-2.jpg" alt="Your company logo" /></div>

 $(document).ready(function(){
$('div.logoImage img').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.wrap('<a href="' + $this.attr('src') + '"></a>');
});
```

});

UPDATE: thinking about it, perhaps it would be easier to also set the 're' attribute of the link whist setting the source?

UPDATE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.logoImage img').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.wrap('<a rel="gallery" href="' + $this.attr('src') + '"></a>');
    });

});
```

Doesn't work for some reason - but it does if i hardcode the URL and rel?

Answer (score 5):

This did the trick...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.logoImage img').each(function(){
        var anchor = $('<a/>').attr({'href': this.src}).colorbox({height: "90%", title: "Your Company Logo"});
        $(this).wrap(anchor);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. Albeit, I modified it a bit to make all my images automagically become Lightbox ready:

$('img').each(function(){
        var anchor = $('<a/>').attr({'href': this.src,'data-lightbox':'myimg'});
        $(this).wrap(anchor);
  });

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's looking, here's the pure javascript version sans the colorbox:

```
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img'));
elements.forEach(function(el, i){
    var newHTML = "<a href='"+ el.src +"'>" + el.outerHTML + "</a>";
    el.outerHTML = newHTML;
});
```